# coloring of a graph after removing a vertex

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be any simple graph (i.e has no loops nor multiple edges) and let $1,2,...,\chi(G)$ be any good coloring to the vertices of $G$(i.e a minimal coloring for its vertices in which each 2 adjacent vertices have different colors).

let $v$ be a vertex in $G$ of color $1$ such that $v$ has no neighbors of color $2$.

show that $\chi(G-\{v\})=\chi(G)$.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: my problem is that if i color the vertices of a graph (in which each 2 adjacent vertices have different colors and with minimal number of colors ) and i want to remove a vertex such that there is some color not obtained in its neighbors , Did the chromatic number still the same? or it will decrease one ?

Comment: I tried to find an example and i see that it will be the same but i couldnt prove it theoretically! Any help please

Comment: What I meant was, where did you find this problem?

Comment: In my work on the stage i have something like that related to forests ... but this is a little bit general.

Comment: So this is something coming up in mathematical research, and not an exercise from a textbook?

Comment: Anyway, if I understand the problem, what you're trying to show is false. Consider a cycle on 5 vertices, colored 1-3-2-1-3. That 1st vertex is colored 1, and its neighbors have color 3, but when you remove it you get a path of length 4 which can, of course, be colored with 2 colors.

Comment: Yea! Its a very good example thanks

Comment: Good. You can write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is false, Indeed,
Consider a cycle of 5 vertices colored by the colors 1,2,1,2,3 then the third vertex colored by color 1 and not adjacent to the color 3, but removing it obtain a path which can be colored by 2 colors.